# Mvc Music Store (MVC3) : SampleData won't populate DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's my really BIG problem: When I run the program it finds NO genres ): [Check the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjULo.png)

The example is using this code as the connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
    connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

As you might notice, It is using SqlServerCe4.0, but instead I change it in order to use SqlClient (wich I have already installed):

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add 
            name="MusicStoreEntities"
             connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;
             Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.mdf"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
      />
</connectionStrings>
```

Sample Data file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicStoreEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
        {
            var genres = new List<Genre>
            {
                //Perfec genres
            };

            var artists = new List<Artist>
            {
                //Cool Artists list
            };

            new List<Album>
            {
                //Awesome albums
            }.ForEach(a => context.Albums.Add(a));

        }
    }
}
```

A context class:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Application Start class:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcMusicStore
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData());

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas of how to solve this problem? I'd appriciate your help.

EDIT 1. Added IdentityModels.cs

IdentityModels.cs

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {


    }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {

            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it have any data at all?

Comment: @Rahul If your talking about the SampleData class, the file is FULL of Artists, Albums and Genres. But, I don't know why isn't populating the Database.

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl Do you have your database present?Perhaps the connectionstring in your example is not valid.

Comment: Hi, @ShawnYan. How do I know if there's a database present? And, Yes I was thinking the same thing, I think I have a problem with my ConnectionString. 

Edit: Omg, I remember that I erase some files inside App_Data folder thinking that they will autogenerate. I think I was having a touble and decided to erase the database there.

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl You need to check whether it exists on your App_Data folder, or your sql server provider.Try with this connectionstring : `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Db_Name;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, you need to do `update-database` on package manager console to seed your data.

Comment: Ok, @ShawnYan. Thank you for waiting and help me.I found 3 inside App_Data folder; MvcMusicStore.mdf, MvcMusicStore.sdf and MvcMusicStore2.mdf. I got this error:  _A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections_ and the exception was found in this line: `var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();`

Comment: @ShawnYan run the command on the package manager and this was the result:

_Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database._

_No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'MvcMusicStore'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)._

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl you need to enable migrations on your project. As for the first error, your connection string is not valid or you don't have the database which doesn't seems the case. :-)

Comment: Ok, @ShawnYan. After running the command VS created a called Configuration.cs, then I rebuild it. But the same exception was found

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl Place your seed method's content into the Configuration.cs Seed method and then `update-database`

Comment: @ShawnYan Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately I'm having I'm having a compile error:
`}.ForEach(a => context.Album.Add(a));` it says that DbApplicationContext does not contain definition for Album

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl Ok go into your IdentityModel.cs file, in it there are suppose to have ApplicationDbContext . That is your default dbcontext so either you use that class to put your DbSets in it or you use the context class in your example.

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl Im adding my DbContext class as answer.Please have a look.

Comment: @ShawnYan Muchas gracias, amigo :D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your context class into something like this :

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MusicStoreEntities()
            : base("MusicStoreEntities")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().ToTable("Album");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().ToTable("Product");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public static MusicStoreEntities Create()
        {
            return new MusicStoreEntities();
        }
    }
}
```

The OnModelCreating creates the table inside the database.

Comment: Should I remove the contents from Configuration.cs?

Comment: Nope you don't need to. Configuration.cs allow you to do seed data and has nothing to do with DbContext. :-)

Comment: Ok. I did as you told me BUT I still get the same error in `.ForEach(a => context.Albums.Add(a));`

Comment: I edited my Question and added IdentityModels.cs ... check it out

Comment: Ok. Hide the whole `ApplicationDbContext` class in IdentityModels.cs and debug again.

Comment: Hide it? You mean, erase it? Or what?

Comment: Yeah erase it .Actually I meant to say comment out the whole `ApplicationDbContext` instead of hide .Pardon me.

Comment: Ok, seems like You got rid of the compile error, But know I have these two errors:
`internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MvcMusicStore.Models.ApplicationDbContext>`
and: `protected override void Seed(MvcMusicStore.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)`

Comment: May I know where do you get this error.Probably somewhere inside your Configuration.cs are still referring `<MvcMusicStore.Models.ApplicationDbContext>`.Change it to your own DbContext `<MvcMusicStore.Models.MusicStoreEntities>`

Comment: And this error in Album.cs at `public class Album : ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: Hmm your model class not suppose to inherit `ApplicationDbContext`.Change it to `public class Album `

Comment: Well, as odd as it may sound ... The same error appeared! _A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)_ I think I'm going to check this error out. Thank you very much for helping an ASP.NET N00b. How can I give you points? Cause I'm really please with your help (:

Comment: @Cempoalxóchitl Nevermind I didn't solve your problem anyway.Maybe you should post this issue as another question though.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code in sample data class and put into the configuration file that was created during enabling the migration. Then I ran a ****enable-migration -force**** code and then **update-database** in package manager console. further i have added the **context.savechange()** at the end of method. And my database was populated with above data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXpSu.png)

Comment: Please edit your post such that the text of your image link indicates the nature/relevance of the image.